# ASP.NET MVC Error: "Name '__o' is not declared."

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a whole bunch of these errors on my View aspx file.

But, It builds and runs just fine.

What are they?  How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mikhail Arkhipov posted an [explanation and workaround in the ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/923745/1266105.aspx):

> We have finally obtained reliable
>   repro and identified the underlying
>   issue. A trivial repro looks like
>   this:
>
> ```
> <% if (true) { %>
>     <%=1%>
> <% } %>
> <%=2%>
> ```
>
> In order to provide intellisense in <%= %> blocks at
>   design time, ASP.NET generates
>   assignment to a temporary __o variable
>   and language (VB or C#) then provide
>   the intellisense for the variable.
>   That is done when page compiler sees
>   the first <%= ... %> block.  But here,
>   the block is inside the if, so after
>   the if closes, the variable goes out
>   of scope.  We end up generating
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> if (true) { 
>     object @__o;
>     @__o = 1;
> }
> @__o = 2;
> ```
>
> The workaround is to add a dummy
>   expression early in the page.  E.g.
>   <%="" %>.  This will not render
>   anything, and it will make sure that
>   __o is declared top level in the Render method, before any potential
>   ‘if’ (or other scoping) statement.

Comment: This is what I love about SO... I learn something new every day.